# How to merge consecutive lines to reflect data from the same record?

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

I was hoping someone can help on Notepad++ or Excel/VBA.

I have the data below (sorry I could not attach the file) but if the example data is copied in Notepad++ it should have 12 lines of data.

Assuming I'm using Notepad++:

- Line 4,5 & 6 are from one record but split across lines.
- Line 7,8,9 are individual records.
- Line 10,11 & 12 are from one record but split across lines.

Could someone please help or let me know of a quick way to display one record-one line so that I can analyse the data? At the moment I risk losing the data integrity of the records.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Finance,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Account_name,Serial Number,AcctNum,Created Date,Updated Date,Number of Digits,Measurement Units,Currency Free Descriptor,Size,Frequency,Return,Object Chargeable Size,Category Chargeable Size,logger(W),logger (NW),AMDX,AMDY,RAD Location Free Descriptor,RAD Outreader GISX,RAD Outreader GISY,RAD Outreader Location Free Descriptor,RAD Treatment,RAD Location Code,Combi RAD Flag,Vol,Remote Flag,Remote Type,Outreader ID,Outreader Protocol,Address – Free Descriptor,Address – Secondary Addressable Object,Address – Primary Addressable Object,Address - Address Line 1,Address - Address Line 2,Address - Address Line 3,Address - Address Line 4,Address - Address Line 5,Address - Postcode,Address - PAF Address Key 

Account_name,94T034862,9911637482NUM19,2014-11-19,,5,pounds,,15,B,100.00,15,15,0,0,535551.0,198661.0,"PANEL RHS OF COLUMN NR CHILLERCABS. BACK OF SHOP BEFORE BAKERY.
",82644.0,5186.0,"PANEL RHS OF COLUMN NR CHILLERCABS. BACK OF SHOP BEFORE BAKERY.
",TAX,I,0,30,0,,,,936065186,,,918,SWINGFORD RD,,MENFIELD,MIDDX,YYY XX1,
Account_name,94T034868,9911429278NUM17,2014-11-07,,5,pounds,,15,B,100.00,15,15,0,0,525425.0,178736.0,CELLAR.TEL.0171 9121401,82644.0,5186.0,CELLAR.TEL.0171 9121401,TAX,I,0,158,0,,,,216031935,,,147,SUPER DEN RD,,MONTY,,YYY 9XX2,
Account_name,94T034871,9910235259NUM13,2015-01-30,,5,pounds,,15,B,100.00,15,15,0,0,518053.0,174903.0,THIS SECTION OF UNION CT ISV IA ALLEY ON RHS OF NO15 SHEENR D (FEATHERSTONE LEIGH)..PROCEE D 30 MTRS ALONG ALLEY.THENUNDE R.ARCH.ON.RHS.TO SHOP T/AS'TEC HISM...MTR BELOW WASH BASIN R/ O PREMISES...,82644.0,5186.0,THIS SECTION OF UNION CT ISV IA ALLEY ON RHS OF NO15 SHEENR D (FEATHERSTONE LEIGH)..PROCEE D 30 MTRS ALONG ALLEY.THENUNDE R.ARCH.ON.RHS.TO SHOP T/AS'TEC HISM...MTR BELOW WASH BASIN R/ O PREMISES...,TAX,I,0,37,0,,,,17644552,,,167,UNION PARK,,BEDMOND,SUNVIL,YYY XX3,
Account_name,94T034887,9910508441NUM12,2014-10-24,,5,pounds,,15,B,100.00,15,15,0,0,540456.0,185014.0,CELLAR FRONT RIGHT,82644.0,5186.0,CELLAR FRONT RIGHT,TAX,I,0,105,0,,,,149388560,,,111 SHOP,GUNFERD RD,,PERL,,YYY XX4,
Account_name,94T034889,9910698216NUM14,2014-11-28,,5,pounds,,15,B,100.00,15,15,0,0,525594.0,178188.0,"IN STORES (SPIRITS) UNDER SHELF ACCESS AFTER 12NOON AS KEY TO SPIRIT STORE NOT AVAILABLE BEFORE 12NOON
",82644.0,5186.0,"IN STORES (SPIRITS) UNDER SHELF ACCESS AFTER 12NOON AS KEY TO SPIRIT STORE NOT AVAILABLE BEFORE 12NOON
",TAX,I,0,30,0,,,,64777361,,,286 SHOP,OLD COMPTON RD,,FETLING,,YYY XXW,
```

Comment: I suggest uploading a screencap of your sample data to http://imgur.com and linking to it. Doing the same for the expected result would also be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Using Notepad++, this will replace all linebreaks that are not followed by the word "Account"

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!Account)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!Account)     # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't the word "Account" after
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank for all the replies and suggestions.

Comment: @FADZZY01: You're welcome, glad it helps, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thank for all the replies and suggestions. Apart from  the fact that I want all records to display as individual lines, I would like to get the 4th value after the value "TAX" appears i.e the zeros and ones so I would like a way to retain that info rather than just replace all the quoted(") strings. Is there a solution for this?Many thanks

Comment: Also I want to add that account name is a variable,I had to anonymise it calling it account name. thanks

Comment: @FADZZY01: Sorry, I don't get you. You've asked to join some separated lines into one. That's what my regex does. If you want something else, please, edit your question and show **exactly** what you want.